# Unable to get data from sessionSorage to send to php class

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, getelementbyid

I am trying to retreive the email of currently logged in user from sessionStorage and send it to php? however it is not working. Can you help me?

```
<?php

$mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$db = $mongoClient->commerce;
$email = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "email", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$findCriteria = [
    "email" => $email, 
];
$cursor = $db->Customer->find($findCriteria);
echo "email is ".$email;
echo "<h1>Results</h1>";
foreach ($cursor as $cust) {
    $name = $cust['name'];
    echo "name: <input type='text' name='name' value='" . $name . "'>";
    echo "<button onclick='save.php'>save new Customer Details</button>";
}
$mongoClient->close();
```

```
function view() {
            request.onload = function () {
                if (request.status === 200) {
                    var responseData = request.responseText;
                    document.getElementById("ViewDetails").innerHTML = responseData;
                } else
                    alert("Error communicating with server: " + request.status);
            };           
            request.open("POST", "view.php");
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");           
            var usrEmail=sessionStorage.getItem("LoggedIn");                        
            request.send("email=" + usrEmail);
        }
```

Comment: can you show us where did you use sessionStorage.setItem("LoggedIn", "email_id");

Comment: this is the piece of code: sessionStorage.setItem("LoggedIn", usrEmail); I added an alert earlier to see if the email was being retrieved. It did work below line 11 in view(). However in view.php the line 10, echo "email is " .$email is not showing me the email.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this in view:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
      console.log('if');
      console.log(sessionStorage.getItem("LoggedIn"));
  }
});
```

Comment: it is generating this error in chrome: Notice: Use of undefined constant document - assumed 'document' in E:\www\Test\view.php on line 8

Fatal error: Call to undefined function ready() in E:\www\Test\view.php on line 8

Comment: can you please help me? I tried everything. Can you suggest me any reason for this happening? Is this because of my browser?

Comment: try this in view <script>
    console.log(typeof(Storage));
</script>

Comment: whenever I try using script tags in view it is highlighted in red. i am using netbeans.

Comment: its ok. problm solved. issue: $email = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "email", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);  Solved by putting INPUT_POST instead of INPUT_GET. Thank you for your help and patience sir.

Comment: hello sir. I am having difficulties in another question. Can you please help me? Here is the link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54804138/unable-to-update-mongodb-collection-via-php